# AngularJS form validation: indicate required fields to user

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I would like my form labels to display a red asterisk next to the label when the corresponding form control has a `required` attribute.

Instead of hard coding the asterisk, I desire a way to append the asterisk to the label dynamically during page load if the label's corresponding input, select or textarea is required (the element the label corresponds to).

I created the directive below, and the directive works.  But is there a better, more native way to accomplish my goal?  This directive finds all the `div.form-group` containers and adds a red `*` character after the label if the corresponding form control inside the div.form-group has a `required` attribute.

```
myApp.directive('labelsRequired',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.find('div.form-group').each(function(i, formGroup){
                var formControls = $(formGroup).find('input, select, textarea');
                console.log(formControls)
                if (0 !== formControls.length && undefined !== $(formControls[0]).attr('required')){
                    jLabel = $(formGroup).find('label');
                    jLabel.html(jLabel.html()+ "<span class='red-color'>*</span>");
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

The directive assumes all inputs, selects, and textareas are inside a `div.form-group` container.

```
<div class='form-group'>
  <label>First Name</label><!-- this label gets an asterisk -->
  <input name='fname' required />
</div>
<div class='form-group'>
  <label>Favorite Food</label><!-- this label does not get an asterisk -->
  <input name='favFood'  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a directive, there are built-in [form properties](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) you can use with filters like `ng-show`, look:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <input name='fname' ng-model="fname" required />
          <label ng-show="userForm.fname.$dirty && userForm.fname.$error.required">* Required field</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you define an `ng-model` for the `input` you can deal with it looking if it is filled or not. You can also check it only after the user "dirty" it with `userForm.fname.$dirty`, so the label will be shown only after a user try to input something but then clear it. Try playing with it [here JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/fxLjabz7/1/)

Comment: I want to communicate the `required` to the user before the error occurs.  A form should communicate `required` fields prior to errors happening, in my UX opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Corey's answer:

I just used compile rather than link, as I saw that my required attribute was not being applied to my input elements. I also included a select tag for any dropdowns that I had.

```
    app.directive('inputRequired', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (elem) {
            elem.find('label').append("<sup><i class='fa fa-asterisk'></i></sup>");
            elem.find('input').attr('required', 'required');
            elem.find('select').attr('required', 'required');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This requires you to include `input-required` on every field.  My solution only requires one directive for the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the built-in Angular validation, you could restructure your directive and attach it to your `.form-group` element. Like this:

```
app.directive('inputRequired', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      elem.find('label').append('<span>*</span>');
      elem.find('input').attr('required', 'required');
    }
  };
});
```

Your HTML would then look like:

```
<div class="form-group" input-required>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Food</label>
  <input name="food" />
</div>
```

However, if you haven't looked into the built-in validation with Angular, I would recommend using it.

Comment: I am using the angular native form validation.  The purpose of the directive is only to put the asterisk on the label in a way which corresponds to the existence or presence of the required attribute.  I'll edit to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This might come too late and it might not be too elegant but it works, if anyone needs it:

```
<label ng-show="userForm.fname.$validators.hasOwnProperty('required')">* Required field</label>
```